# Need a multi-optimization environment or plugin in Anylogic

Tags: multi-objective-optimization, simulation

currently I am working on a model to simulate the supply chain of a group of warehouses in a country using Anylogic. Then I need to multi-optimize these outputs to get the best one based on optimizing several functions. As I know, I can use an optimization experiment in Anylogic, but what about multi-optimization ?

Any ideas to multi-optimize inside Anylogic environment ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you can do multi-objective optimization in Anylogic, you could assign weights to all of your cost functions and consolidate them into a unique objective function. In that way, you obtain one solution, but you could make several scenarios changing the weights.

But also, you could check [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andranik-Akopov/publication/262166627_A_Multi-agent_Genetic_Algorithm_for_Multi-objective_Optimization/links/5c802c60299bf1268d404df5/A-Multi-agent-Genetic-Algorithm-for-Multi-objective-Optimization.pdf) and try to replicate in a modern version of Anylogic. In that way, you can obtain the Pareto Frontier.

Another different approach is the one [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XR5dS6bczIA) and [here](https://www.anylogic.com/resources/case-studies/pet-food-production-optimization-using-manufacturing-process-simulation-software/).